# ant design Tab switching when button is presssed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, antd

How to change the tabpane of antd tab, when i clicked a button i want a modal to open and according to that button tabs would switch such as i click on withdraw i want the tab to switch to withdraw tab.
Here is the button code where i will navigate to the modal page of antd inside that modal tab is mounted.

```
 const cryptoDeposit = (d) => {
    
    props?.navigate("wallets/deposit");
};
const cryptoWithdraw = (d) => {
    
    props?.navigate("/wallets/withdraw");
};
const cryptoTransfer = (d) => {
    
    props?.navigate("/wallets/transfer");
};
```

here is the modal page where tab is mounted i have only linked 3 tabs deposite, withdraw and transfer.

```
const { name } = useParams();
useEffect(() => {
    if (name) {
        setActiveTab(name);
        changeTab(name);
    } else {
        changeTab(activeTab);
    }
}, []);

const changeTab = (key) => {
    setActiveTab(key);
    if (activeTab === "deposit") {
        props?.navigate("/wallets/deposit");
    
    } else if (activeTab === "withdraw") {
        props?.navigate("/wallets/withdraw");
        
    } else if (activeTab === "transfer") {
        props?.navigate("/wallets/transfer");
        
    }
};

<Modal
            className="custom-modal"
            visible={activeDeposit}
            title={props?.depositreducer?.depositCryptoObj?.walletCode}
            closeIcon={
                <Tooltip title="Close">
                    <span className="icon md close" onClick={handleCancel} />
                </Tooltip>
            }
            footer={null}>
            
            <Tabs
                tabBarStyle={{ color: "var(--textWhite)", marginBottom: 0 }}
                className="custom-tabs"
                activeTab={activeTab}
                onChange={(e) => changeTab(e)}>
                <TabPane tab="Deposit" key="deposit">
                    
                    {console.log("Active tab", activeTab)}
                    {activeTab === "deposit" && (
                        <div> Deposite Crypto </div>
                    )}
                </TabPane>
                <TabPane tab="Deposit Fiat" key="depositFiat">
                    <div className="mt-24 text-white"> Deposite Fiat </div>

                </TabPane>
                <TabPane tab="Withdraw" key="withdraw">
                    
                    {activeTab === "withdraw" && (
                        <div>this is Withdraw tab </div>
                    )}
                </TabPane>
                <TabPane tab="Withdraw Fiat" key="withdrawfiat">
                    <FaitWithdrawal
                        coinName={props?.depositreducer?.depositCryptoObj?.walletCode}
                    />
                </TabPane>
                <TabPane tab="transfer" key="transfer">
                    {activeTab === "transfer" && (
                        <div> this is transfer tab
                </TabPane>
            </Tabs>
  </Modal>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following example: When you mount the modal, it will check if we have name then set the active tab and show the modal. (I also add a check in `name` so that we can only show a tab that we want to).
You do not need to have if check in `changeTab` function. Since we use already have set the key in `<TabPane`, you can set the key in props?.navigate(`/wallets/${key}`);

Hope its solve your problem

```
const Container = (props) => {
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('deposit');
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

    const { name } = useParams();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (name && ['deposit', 'withdraw', 'transfer'].includes(name)) {
            setActiveTab(name);
            setModalVisible(true);
        }
    }, [name]);

    const changeTab = (key) => {
        setActiveTab(key);
        props?.navigate(`/wallets/${key}`);
    };

    const handleCancel = () => setModalVisible(false);

    // const onNavigate = (tabType) => {
    //     changeTab(tabType);
    //     setModalVisible(true);
    // };

    return (
        <>
            {/* <Button onClick={onNavigate.bind(null, 'deposit')}>Deposit</Button>
            <Button onClick={onNavigate.bind(null, 'withdraw')}>Withdraw</Button>
            <Button onClick={onNavigate.bind(null, 'transfer')}>Transfer</Button> */}
            <Modal
                className='custom-modal'
                visible={modalVisible}
                // title={props?.depositreducer?.depositCryptoObj?.walletCode}
                title='Modal'
                footer={
                    <Button type='primary' onClick={handleCancel}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                }
            >
                <Tabs tabBarStyle={{ color: 'var(--textWhite)', marginBottom: 0 }} className='custom-tabs' activeKey={activeTab} onChange={changeTab}>
                    <TabPane tab='Deposit' key='deposit'>
                        <h1> Deposite Crypto </h1>
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab='Withdraw' key='withdraw'>
                        <h1>this is Withdraw tab </h1>
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab='transfer' key='transfer'>
                        <h1> this is transfer tab</h1>
                    </TabPane>
                </Tabs>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
};
```